# Get Qt stylesheet from Python app

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Is there a way to "rip" Qt stylesheet from Python app?

`.styleSheet()` returns an empty string.

Comment: what do you expect to get when you "rip" it? How are you going to use the result?

Comment: Apply style to a another app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming two things:

1. The app has implemented its styling using stylesheets, and
2. The app uses an application-wide stylesheet.

Either of these assumptions is wrong in your case. You might need to extract stylesheets from individual widgets. Or the application might be using a custom `QStyle` and not stylesheets.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to loop through all widgets and get styles or palettes. Maybe there is easier way?

Comment: @SAF No, there isn't :(